# summing up percentile

Tags: statistics

I have two sets of speed data for a route with different sample size. Let’s say I have 95 percentile speed from point A to B and 95 percentile speed from pint B to C. what is the 95 percentile from point B to C ? I do not think so I can sum up percentile?

Note: I do not have the data I just have the percentile numbers

Thanks